# Unable to edit msgraph seriescollection

Tags: ms-access, charts, vba

I am pulling out my hair trying to parse data or edit into a msgraph series collection. 
I get `error 438 - object does not support this property or method`.

I can manipulate other properties that the object has such as ChartTitle.Font.Size but not the seriescollection.

Intellisencing is not working wth this object which leads me to susspect that I have not set a particular reference.

Sections of the code is below.
The main routine gets the object:

```
strReportName = "Security Selection"
strChartName = "MACD_Chart"

DoCmd.OpenReport strReportName, acViewDesign
Set rptMACD = Reports(strReportName)
Set chartMACD = rptMACD(strChartName)
```

A data recordset is built then all of it is passed into the subroutine:

```
 Call UpdateChart(chartMACD, rstMACD)


Public Sub UpdateChart(chartPlot As Object, rstChart As ADODB.Recordset)          
'FUNCTION:
'       a chart object is passed into the routine,
'       source data is update to the recordset being passed in.
Dim lngType As Long
Dim i, j, iFieldCount As Integer
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim arXValues() As Date
Dim arValues() As Double
Dim strChartName, strYAxis, strXAxis As String
Dim ChrtCollection As ChartObjects

Dim colmCount As Integer
chartPlot.RowSourceType = "Table/Query"

'get number of columns in chart table/Query
iFieldCount = rstChart.Fields.Count

 With chartPlot
'change chart data to arrays of data from recordset
    .Activate
    j = 0
    rstChart.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rstChart.EOF
        j = j + 1
        ReDim Preserve arXValues(1 To j)
        arXValues(j) = rstChart.Fields("Date").Value
        rstChart.MoveNext
    Loop

    For i = 1 To iFieldCount - 1   'Date is first field
        j = 0
        rstChart.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rstChart.EOF   'get next array of data
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve arValues(1 To j)
            arValues(j) = rstChart.Fields(i + 1).Value
            rstChart.MoveNext
        Loop
        .SeriesCollection(i).Name = rstChart.Fields(i + 1).Name
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = arXValues
        .SeriesCollection(i).Values = arValues

    Next i
 end sub
```

I've tried many things and now I'm totally confused. I've also been trying to parse in recordsets (which is my preference) but i'll take anything at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Before continuing: I recommend setting the Chart's `Rowsource` property to a query that returns the data you want and then `Requery`ing the Chart. This is *WAY* easier than the following.**

You are getting the `Error 438` because `Name, XValues, Values` are not properties of the `Series` Object. [MSDN Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa208340%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

That being said, here is a go at your method and some recommendations for doing it that way. The `SeriesCollection` doesn't contain the values associated with MSGraph points like it does in Excel. You need to edit the data in the DataSheet, which is VERY finicky. A reference to the Microsoft Graph Library must be included. This was tested to work with my database. [Microsoft Graph MSDN info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa297308%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

**DAO**

```
Public Sub testing()
Dim rstChart As Recordset
Dim seri As Object, fld As Field
Dim app As Graph.Chart

chartPlot.SetFocus
Set app = chartPlot.Object
Set rstChart = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DateTime, ASIMeasured FROM Surv_ASI WHERE CycleID = 2 ORDER BY DateTime")

app.Application.DataSheet.Range("00:AA1000").Clear

With rstChart
    For Each fld In .Fields
        app.Application.DataSheet.Range("a1:AA1").Cells(0, fld.OrdinalPosition) = fld.Name
    Next

    Do While Not .EOF
        For Each fld In .Fields
            app.Application.DataSheet.Range("a2:AA1000").Cells(.AbsolutePosition, fld.OrdinalPosition).Value = fld
        Next
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

app.Refresh
End Sub
```

**ADO** (Assuming `rstChart` is already a valid ADODB.Recordset)

```
Public Sub testing()
Dim app As Graph.Chart, i As Integer

chartPlot.SetFocus
Set app = chartPlot.Object

app.Application.DataSheet.Range("00:AA1000").Clear

With rstChart
    .MoveFirst 'Since I don't know where it was left off before this procedure.

    For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
        app.Application.DataSheet.Range("a1:AA1").Cells(0, i) = .Fields(i).Name
    Next

    Do While Not .EOF
        For i = 0 To .Fields.Count - 1
            app.Application.DataSheet.Range("a2:AA1000").Cells(.AbsolutePosition, i).Value = .Fields(i)
        Next
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With

app.Refresh
End Sub
```

Some notes about my changes:
1. I prefer having my `With` point to the Recordset being cycled, instead of the Object being operated on, especially since more calls are made to the Recordset's properties in your procedure.
2. You don't need to specify the variable to which a `Next` applies (`Next i`). Just put `Next`.
3. Please pick my answer if it helped :)

Comment: Hi @usncahill. the recordset that I use is the result of a moving algorithm (such as MACD and RSI indicators). I am unsure how to do this in a query form. is there a better way to update or create a chart? Essentially I want to put a chart in a form with data that I have created (array, recordset or query... I'm not fussy).

Comment: @ian Where is the recordset 'rstChart' coming from? How does it relate to the MACD and RSI? Are these generated on a per-record basis (i.e. each record is a day/hour/minute that has the moving average created for it)?

Comment: @usnacahill. MACD is generated from a script, which is then popuated into a recordset. an example is'                dEMAS(iCount) = (curPrice * dEXPSlowWeight) + (dEMAS(iCount - 1) * (1 - dEXPSlowWeight))   '

Comment: @usnacahill. As you can see the last result of dEMAS calc is feed into the current calc. dEMAS is an array, in this case it goes thru several other calcs to generate the final value but these are linear type calcs (+/-*) which I have no problems with.

Comment: @ian Are the variables above (dEXPSlowWeight, curPrice) in an existing table? You say MACD is 'populated into a recordset', meaning it's saved to a table? In this case, I would make a query for that table, returning the value list you want and set the graph Rowsource to it.

Comment: @usnacahill, I tried your code, but my recordset is an ADO and yours is an DOA. It fails at the .ordinalpposition. I am unsuccessfully trying to find the field number property as a substitute.

Comment: @usnacahill, Raw data (curPrice) is in an a table, variables (dEXPSlowWeight) are passed into the function or are defined in the function. the values are added to the recordset directly using the .addnew method. I could create a table and populate it using the same methodology but I am conscious of maintaining consistancy with other parts of this program. Meaning that generally I return recordsets from these types of functions.

Comment: @ian I do not much about ADODB. Manipulating the recordset looks similar enough and so I have provided an ADO method above.